# why does __block not adding values to array

Tags: objective-c, block, nsindexset, nsblockoperation

I am enumerating ranges inside a block and storing the values inside an array. I expected using __block should store the values inside block into array?

```
 __block  NSMutableArray *array;
  [indexSet enumerateRangesUsingBlock:^(NSRange range,BOOL * stop ) {

    [array addObject:@(range.location)];
    [array addObject:@(range.length)];

     NSLog(@"location is %d, %ld", range.location, range.length);


}];


NSLog(@"%@",array );
```

But this result in

> location is 4, 2  location is 8, 2  location is 14, 2

and for array

> (null)

I expected array to be filled with values.

Comment: You might want to alloc/init the `array` first.

Comment: The `__block` is not needed, even once you do allocate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize it, a just declared array is `nil`:

```
__block  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

(The Swift compiler would throw an error ...  )

Comment: Vadian, you forgot to explain that the `__block` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

__block  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

It does work fine.

However when I declared array as property then block became redundant.

Comment: `__block` was *always* redundant. The attribute allows you to change the value of the variable `array` within your block, you are not doing that, it's value remains the same - it always references the *same* array. It is the mutable array whose content changes.